# Using JSON dict in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to access certain fields of information in JSON dict. My code is set up as the following:

**Views.py**

```
def viewIssues(request):
    r = requests.get(bucket_url)
    issue_payload = r.json()
    issue = json.loads(str(issue_payload))

    context = {
        "issue_title": issue['issues']['title'],
        "issue_content": issue['issues']['content'],
        "title": "View Issues",
    }
   return render(request, "view_issues.html", context)
```

str(issue_payload) gives me this:

```
    {  
   'search':None,
   'count':1,
   'filter':{  

    },
   'issues':[  
      {  
         'priority':'major',
         'comment_count':0,
         'utc_created_on':'2016-11-12 01:48:16+00:00',
         'utc_last_updated':'2016-11-12 01:48:16+00:00',
         'status':'new',
         'title':'example issue',
         'reported_by':{  
            'is_staff':False,
            'display_name':'display name',
            'is_team':False,
            'resource_uri':'/1.0/users/username',
            'avatar':'https://bitbucket.org/account/username/avatar/32/?ts=1479493904',
            'first_name':'firstname',
            'username':'username',
            'last_name':'lastname'
         },
         'is_spam':False,
         'content':'blah blah',
         'metadata':{  
            'milestone':None,
            'component':None,
            'version':None,
            'kind':'bug'
         },
         'local_id':1,
         'created_on':'2016-11-12T02:48:16.052',
         'resource_uri':'/1.0/repositories/username/supportal2016test/issues/1',
         'follower_count':1
      }
   ]
}
```

However when I try to use the json.loads and indices ['issues']['title'] and ['issues']['title'] I get an error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I'm wondering if it's because the converted payload has quotations on each field (i.e. 'issues'). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't valid JSON. Should be double quotes for strings. You can't use either quote types like Python. What you actually have is Python representation of the objects and not JSON. You don't need to decode it yourself as the ``json()`` method already did it for you. You end up with Python representation because you use ``str()`` on what were already Python objects.

Comment: Just remove this line `issue = json.loads(str(issue_payload))` and use `issue_payload`; it is already a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

The `.json()` call already parses the JSON result and returns a Python structure in this case a dictionary. Then your call

```
issue = json.loads(str(issue_payload))
```

forces the dictionary into a string and tries to parse it again. But the dictionary string representation contains `'` around strings and not `"` as required in JSON.

To cut the long story short: `issue_payload` is what you want already.